# reactjs material-ui and redux form fields -- creating component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a fields component using react redux forms -- and have it so it generates multiple fields using the material ui forms.

this works using standard input fields

```
const renderTextField2 = (fields) => (
  <div>
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...fields.firstName.input} type="text"/>
      {fields.firstName.meta.touched && fields.firstName.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{fields.firstName.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...fields.lastName.input} type="text"/>
      {fields.lastName.meta.touched && fields.lastName.meta.error &&
       <span className="error">{fields.lastName.meta.error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

but I want to explore or loop through to make the relevant fields - this the current state of development -- I want to put a console log here to see what "fields" is - but it will reject anywhere I place it.

```
const renderTextField2 = (fields) => (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth={true}>   
      <FormLabel component="legend">mmm </FormLabel>
      <FormGroup
        row
      >
          <Field {...fields.firstName.input} component={renderTextField} label="" />
          <Field {...fields.lastName.input} component={renderTextField} label="" />
      </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
)


export default renderTextField2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something like this working - but I need to make it checkboxes

```
const renderTextField2 = (fields) => (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth={true}>   
      <FormLabel component="legend">mmm </FormLabel>
      <FormGroup
        row
      >
          {            
            fields.names.map((item, j) => {
              return(
                <Field key={j} {...fields[item].input} component={renderTextField} label="" />
              )
            })      
          }
      </FormGroup>
    </FormControl>
)


export default renderTextField2;
```